# Excel; how to extract a middle text that changes

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, extract

I'm trying to extract:

```
questionLabel9 
questionLabel10 

 @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel9: UILabel!
 

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel10: UILabel!
```

the list continues but the @IBOutlet weak var  and  : UILabel! stays always same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@IBOutlet weak var",""),": UILabel!",""))
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for ! this is correct !!!!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it seem you could also use:

```
=MID(A1,20,FIND(":",A1)-20)
```

Comment: But what if text size (questionlabel10) changes to "Hello" ?

Comment: @JalalMirahmadi, than it would retrieve `Hello`.